How to update Main Git Repository with local directories with code changes?
I am going to clarify the working conditions to explain why we have worked in this way.
The computer for development is in a completely isolated work environment, without connection to any data network, all data ports are disabled (network, USB, Bluetooth, etc.) so there is no possibility of copying the source code towards a more open environment.
This computer only has Visual Studio 2022 installed, no other type of software has been installed, which is why it is impossible to create branches from the master since VS 2022 does not allow branches connected to local directories.
The only way that could be used to isolate daily changes was to create a directory each day, by means of a copy from Windows File Explorer, containing the changes made during the last and previous days.
The structure of the project would be as follows:

CS_2024-04-10 directory, this is the original directory containing the original source code. This directory was converted to a GIT repository using VS 2022 which allows us to have the master branch. Because of the above, this directory contains the hidden .git directory.

The next day, a copy of the original directory was made, and this copy was named CS_2024-04-11. Because of this, this directory contains the hidden .git directory of the original. We worked on this copy by opening the project in VS 2022 and making various changes and then saving the results.

The previous process has been carried out for two weeks, so there are 10 source code directories which include the changes made during each workday plus the changes from the respective previous day, for example, the directory CS_2024-04- 16 contains all the changes made from day 10 to day 15 plus the changes made during day 16.


Now, what we need is to know if it is possible to convert all these sequential directories into a GIT structure with change control such as the first directory with the master branch and then branches that can be associated with each subsequent directory.
I have installed, to support the idea, the GIT program. For this reason, now the development computer only contains two software for development, Visual Studio 2022, and GIT.
How would it be possible to create branches from the master branch, using the original directory CS_2024-04-10 and associate these branches with the sequential directories created?
Using git worktree does not help since the directories must be empty and, after creating the new branch, replacing the content with the existing content in the previous directories does not work.

It sounds like each folder has a .git folder in it, but it isn't clear if that repository is being used at all? Was it ever used, or can it be discarded? Or, maybe you only need to start with the first .git folder and the rest are no longer needed since there are no new commits in them?

@TTT What I need is to generate, in some way, version control to see the changes made each day in the same way as when one creates a branch and commits.

Does this answer your question? How to merge between two local repositories

I think I understand your end goal. I'm asking about the existing .git folders. Did you ever make any commits in any of the Git repos, the first one, or otherwise?

@TTT, No commits were ever made on each copy, only changes were made and the next day a copy of the last directory in the sequence was made. Each directory was loaded into VS 2022 as if it were the first copy, the copy was never transformed into a repository.

I got a suggestion from a GIT email user and it solved my problem. Below I describe the process so that if anyone else requires something similar they can see how the process was carried out.
You need to convert the first directory in the sequence to a git repository.
I run Git bash on the directory CS_2024-04-10 and,

In the Git repo of day 1, CS_2024-04-10, I removed all files except for the .git folder. This is to make sure that any files that are no longer present on the next day are really no longer in the repo.

I copied the content of the second day, CS_2024-04-11, except the .git folder over into CS_2024-04-10. git status, git diff etc should show the differences between CS_2024-04-10 and CS_2024-04-11.

I create a new branch for CS_2024-04-11, I executed the command
git checkout -b 2024-04-11

From Git gui, stage and commit the branch.

From git bash, run the command:
git checkout master
and
git merge 2024-04-11 (the branch created for the copied files)

Continue from step 1 to 5 for each remaining day, CS_2024-04-12...CS_2024-04-20.


This process leaves me a repository with a record of all the changes made, grouped by each day in its own branch and VS 2022 now shows the entire change process and file version control.

Some tips: make sure to run git status in the starting point in case that folder wasn't committed yet. This would be step 0 in your list. Also, branches are actually just pointers to commits, so you could just make a daily commit all on one branch. Having a separate branch per day may not actually be needed, but if for some reason you wanted that in the future you could always create those branches retroactively to point to whichever commits you'd like. Lastly, if you haven't already, make sure you get a sensible .gitignore file setup in step 0. (I'd start over if you skipped this step.)
